# hadoop in win10, hadoop version will cause can't find class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo，how should I do?

Tags: shell, hadoop, cmd

hadoop have two files to start( hadoop  and hadoop.sh),  Because I use win10, hadoop.cmd is automatically called, I know that the hadoop version problem can be solved by modifying the exce command in the hadoop file, but the hadoop file is a shell language and the system will automatically call the .cmd file. How can I modify

```sh
"exec" $ JAVA "-classpath" $ (cygpath- pw "$ CLASSPATH") "$ JAVA_HEAP_MAX $ HADOOP_OPTS $ CLASS" $ @ "
```

This command becomes a .cmd command? I don't know .cmd instructions

Answer (score 0):

Rather than edit your shell scripts (because they work for plenty of other people), you should extract Hadoop to a location that contains no spaces or special characters.

For example, c:\hadoop rather than your downloads folder

Comment: D:\hadoop-2.7.1 this my hadoop location。 There are no spaces in it

Comment: And what about your Java installation location?